# Add/Change Drive Letter Causes BSOD

Tags: windows-7, bsod, service-pack, drive-letter

Recently Microsoft Support had me "upgrade" or rather replace the installation of Windows because I had an SFC error that could not be resolved any other way, apparently.

SFC now runs without reporting any errors.

but now

All "new" external drives to my system cause a BSOD when adding of changing a drive letter.

I have 3 external drives.

disk 1: 1TB is an hard drive previously used on the system with Windows prior to the recent upgrade and is still recognised and is in use without issue.

disk 2: 1GB is a flash disk previously used on the system with Windows prior to the recent upgrade, but now requires drivers to be installed. After drivers are installed automatically, the system BSODs.

disk 3: 2TB is a new drive which also behaves in the same way as disk 2 causing a BSOD.

**All of the drives can be seen and used connected to the same system when running Linux.**

This means there is an issue with the new installation of Windows.

Things I have tried:

**Disk Management**

With disk 3, Disk Management enumerates the drive and allows me to use the New Simple Volume Wizard. I use the following settings:

- Volume Size: Defaults to "1907727MB"
- Assign Following Drive Letter: set to "do not assign drive letter path"
- Format this volume: defaults to NTFS
- Allocation Size: "Default"
- Volume Label: defaults to "New Volume"
- Perform Quick Format: default Checked.
- Enable File and Folder compression: default Unchecked.

The Wizard starts the job, an egg timer sits there for a while, no other information is displayed, I would have hoped for "formatting" to pop up with the drive listing.

When complete the wizard comes up with the following error:

> "The operation failed to complete because the Disk Management view is
>   not up-to-date."

Restarting the system does not change the situation and I am unable to add or change the drive letter.

**Disk Management (specify drive letter)**

If in Windows Disk Management I follow the same proceedure above but during the wizard I assign a drive letter ("X:"), the wizard does not show an egg timer, but instead says "formatting", which looks more usual.

But then, when the wizard completes, I momentarily see "Healthy, Primary Disk" and then I get a BSOD and memory dump.

On reboot of Windows the same BSOD occurs after loading the desktop.

**Diskpart.exe**

Using diskpart.exe

- `automount disable` to allow the drive to be visible but not mounted
- `select disk 3`
- `clean` the partition table
- `create partition primary`
- `format fs=ntfs quick`
- (Device Manager) uninstall the drivers for the disk.
- Back in diskpart `automount enable`
- `assign letter=y`

I see the drivers being automatically installed and momentarily see the autorun box pop up with the drive letter and then BSOD again.

**Device Manager**

I have seen reports of people finding Unknown Device in the Device Manager. I too have found this and uninstalled the Unknown Device, and also uninstalled the known device, disconnected and reconnected the device to see the drivers automatically install and a BSOD result.

Disk 3 behaves in this way whether connected by eSATA or USB interface.

Windows Updates are up to date, and the system BIOS is up to date.

Windows 7 Pro 64-bit SP1 - Dell M4400 - Nvidia FX770

### Found the BSOD

> A problem has been detected and Windows has been shut down to prevent
>   damage to your computer.
>
> The problem seems to be caused by the following file: ntoskrnl.exe
>
> SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION
>
> If this is the first time you've seen this stop error screen, restart
>   your computer. If this screen appears again, follow these steps:
>
> Check to make sure any new hardware or software is properly installed.
>   If this is a new installation, ask your hardware or software
>   manufacturer for any Windows updates you might need.
>
> If problems continue, disable or remove any newly installed hardware
>   or software. Disable BIOS memory options such as caching or shadowing.
>   If you need to use safe mode to remove or disable components, restart
>   your computer, press F8 to select Advanced Startup Options, and then
>   select Safe Mode.
>
> Technical Information:
>
> *** STOP: 0x0000003b (0x00000000c0000005, 0xfffff80002aa8157,
>   0xfffff88007d5bd30,  0x0000000000000000)
>
> *** ntoskrnl.exe - Address 0xfffff80002ad7c40 base at
>   0xfffff80002a5b000 DateStamp  0x4e02aaa3

Comment: All of that text … and nowhere a mention of what the `STOP` error message *actually is*. ☺

Comment: I would start over and "Clean" install windows.

Comment: @JdeBP How can I get the STOP error message ? it goes by too quick to write down in time.

Comment: Take a look a the crash dump with something like http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html and see if you can find any cluse.

Comment: @jmreicha Thanks I just remembered I had NirSoft's app on the system and that's how I found the info at the bottom of the post. But I'm none the wiser as to the cause based on that info.

Comment: @timoto - Save yourself a great deal of work and just reinstall Windows.  You could also make sure you have install ALL updates.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't feel I'm learning very much by re-installing. I'd rather learn how this issue has been created so that I can avoid it in the future and also discover if there are any less time-consuming remedies. Do you know something about this particular issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I got a response from Microsoft Support directly who asked me to follow this proceedure:

> please try to uninstall the security software and then uninstall and
>   reinstall the Display Adapter Drivers and then check the status of the
>   issue

I uninstalled MSSE, Malwarebytes and Nvidia drivers, then installed the Nvidia drivers.

I inserted disk 2, but it still didn't come up in Explorer. Having no faith in the following I tried it again anyway: Went to Device Manager once more and uninstalled the "unknown device" and the "known device" and re-scaned for PnP hardware.

**Boink !** It showed up in Explorer and **no BSOD**.

Disk 3 connected and required no further attention as it was recognised instantly in Explorer.

The uninstall/install process took a total of 30 mins. I didn't learn a hell of a lot but it was a better solution to hours re-installing Windows and all my software and settings.It's worth hanging on a little longer before breaking out the Windows install disk.

Comment: Yeah, low low level BSODs can be a pain in the rear to diagnose.

Comment: Tell me about it, I saw my first one back in '93. The PlugnPlay mirage continues to evade microsoft.

Comment: You could learn yet more by reading [the documentation for that STOP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff558949%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @JdeBP Thanks, there is a smidgen more info there. :)

Comment: Generally not a clever idea to run multiple anti-malware solutions (MSSE and Malwarebytes in your case). And by that I mean solutions with a separate filter driver such as those from two different vendors. It's a different story if your anti-malware product employs multiple AM engines under the hood, but these are all called from one driver.